# Proof check for Putnam practice problem

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

I realize this is simply an A1 problem, but my proof seems way too simple, so I would like someone to point out whether or not it's correct (and most importantly, fix any flaws in it).

**Problem.**
Suppose that a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ satisfies $0 < a_n \leq a_{2n} + a_{2n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Prove that the series $\sum _{n = 1} ^\infty a_n$ diverges.

**Solution.** From the given conditions, $$a_1 \leq a_2 + a_3 \leq a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7 \leq \ . \ . \ 
.$$

Thus, $$a_1 + (a_2 + a_3) + (a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7) + ... \geq a_1 + a_1 + a_1 + ...$$

Which diverges, since $a_1 > 0$.

Comment: I just did this one the other day too! I believe that works perfectly :)

Comment: You have used some thing without proof, in fact you beleived that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}(\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k})
$$
This is grouping terms. There exist some theorems in books dealing with this
matter. In particular, if the left series converges, then equality holds,
but you have to proof in our case that precisely the left series diverges!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment above, there is a theorem which says that we can sum by grouping and we
obtain the same sum if the series is convergent. So, this may be added to
your comparison idea to complete the raisonning of the proof as follows.

Assume the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j},$ converges to some $a,$ then
we have equality of grouping%
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}(\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k})
$$
but 
$$
(\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k})\geq (2^{n}-2^{n-1})a_{1}=2^{n-1}a_{1}
$$
then it must follow that%
$$
\infty >a=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}2^{n-1}a_{1}=a_{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }2^{n-1}=+\infty .
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a reference to this theorem?

Comment: John F. Randolph, Basic Real and Abstract analysis, Academic press, 1968, Sect. 3-8, Theorem 4, page 151.

Comment: All you need is the fact that if a sequence of terms is non-negative, then convergence is independent of rearranging and grouping. The theorem requires more machinery as it also needs to deal with negative terms that might potentially cancel out. E.g. the sequence 1, -1, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.25, -0.25, + 0.25, - 0.25, + 0.25, - 0.25, + 0.25, -0.25, may not converge to 0 when we rearrange the terms to get +1, -1, +0.5, + 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, + 0.25, +0.25, +0.25, +0.25, ...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is one more thing you could do to be more thorough. They love not giving people points on the Putnam, so it'd be safest to show that the sum diverges by showing that its sequence of partial sums $s_m=\sum _{n=1} ^ma_n$ diverges. So here's what I would do...

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $2^k\leq m\leq 2^{k+1}$. [Note that $k$ is the largest natural number less than or equal to $\log_2 m$]

Consider $s_m=\sum _{n=1} ^ma_n=a_1+\cdots+a_m$, the $m^{th}$ partial sum of $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty}a_n$.

Then $s_m=a_1+\cdots+a_m\geq a_1+\cdots+a_{2^k}$  (since all $a_i>0$).

But, grouping by powers of $2$ (and dropping the final $a_{2^k}$ term) we get: $$s_m\geq a_1+\cdots+a_{2^k}>(a_1)+(a_2+a_3)+(a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7)+\cdots+(a_{2^{k-1}}+\cdots+a_{2^k-1})\geq a_1+a_1+(a_2+a_3)+\cdots+(a_{2^{k-2}}+a_{2^{k-2}+1}+\cdots+a_{2^{k-1}-2}+a_{2^{k-1}-1})\geq a_1+\cdots+a_1=ka_1$$

(There's exactly one $a_1$ per group. Thus there will be  $k\ $ $a_1$'s, since there were k groups [since $2^k-1=2^0+2^1+\cdots+2^{k-1}$])

Since $k$ is the largest natural number less than or equal to $\log_2m$, we know that $k>\log_2m-1$.

Therefore, because $\log_2m\rightarrow \infty$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$, we have that $ka_1\rightarrow \infty$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$.

Hence $s_m$ diverges. Thus $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty}a_n$ diverges. $\checkmark$

Answer (score 0):

I see no flaw in your work, Since $a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ will cover all numbers when you sum up the n's from 1 to infinity, you can express this sum as a sum of $a_1$'s which diverges since $a_1>0$, simply showing that since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_1 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_1$ diverges, then so must $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_n$

Comment: The flaw is the fact assuming implicitly equality of grouping terms without any proof of the equality.

Comment: @Idris I may have misunderstood your statement but to me it seems pretty clear that if $a_1\leq a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ then the sum of all $a_{2n+1}+a_{2n}$ terms would still be greater than or equal to the sum of all $a_1$. I saw your comment, and i would be interested to learn more about why i am wrong here and possibly an example that contradicts my logic.

Comment: 1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1 ....is a divergent series since its general term do not converges to 0. Now put parenthesis like this, (1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+....it converges to 0. So in general we cannot put parenthesis just because we want that. We should have a proof which allows us to do it. Well, now back to your reasonning. Your reasonning is correct when you said''then the sum of all $a_{2n+1}+a_{2n}$ terms would be ....the sum of all $a_1$. Then you can conclude that the sum diverges, it is OK. But...follows in the next comment, i have no enough space here.

Comment: Your reasoning to prove that the sum of the all the terms $
a_{2n+1}+a_{2n}$ diverges is correct (comparison thm).
However what you are using in your reasoning (probably without knowing that
you use it) is the fact that you believe that the sum you proved that it
diverges is the same as the sum of all $a_{j}.$ The error is to believe
that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k})=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty
}a_{j}
$$
then you conclude the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}$ diverges. (In other words, you prove correctly that a series diverges and you conclude
that an other diverges.)

Answer (score 0):

In such simple cases, I prefer to resort to proof by induction.  For any positive integer $n$, let $C(n)$ be the claim $$C(n) : S_n = \sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1} a_k \ge a_1.$$  Then the claim $$C(1) : S_1 = a_1 \ge 1 \cdot a_1$$ is trivially true.  Thus there exists at least one positive integer $n$ such that $C(n)$ is true.  Then $$S_{n+1} = \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} a_k = \sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n - 1} a_{2k} + a_{2k+1} \ge \sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n - 1} a_k = S_n \ge a_1$$ which shows that if $C(n)$ is true, then $C(n+1)$ is also true.  So by the induction hypothesis, $C(n) : S_n \ge a_1$ is true for all positive integers $n$.  It immediately follows that for any positive integer $N$, $$\sum_{k=1}^{2^N-1} a_k = \sum_{n=1}^N S_n \ge N a_1,$$ and since $a_1 > 0$, by the Archimedean property of the reals, for any $M > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ for which $N a_1 > M$.

If the infinite sum is convergent, then any sequence of partial sums of its terms without rearrangement must also be bounded; but this contradicts the above conclusion, therefore the sum must diverge.

This proof is rather over-the-top with respect to rigor, but Putnam grading is extremely picky.

Comment: In which Putnam did find this (which year?)

Comment: Putnam 1994, A1.