# Does grouping the terms of a series (but not moving them) change the sum?

Tags: summation

This question is an extension of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049433/proof-check-for-putnam-practice-problem) one, in which I am told that, given a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$, $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }a_{j}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}(\sum_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}-1}a_{k})$$

is only true when $\sum _{j = 1} ^{\infty} a_j$ converges. This seems counterintuitive to me (though I know sometimes intuition can be a dangerous thing when dealing with infinities). Is there a place I can read more about this, and are there any easy concrete examples of equality not holding?

Comment: Counterintuitive or not, how do you suggest to *define* the LHS when $\sum\limits_ja_j$ does not converge? And if the LHS is not defined, how can it be equal to... anything?

Answer (score 2):

Think of $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots=1-(1-1)-(1-1)-\dots$